# Trying to found a query with 4 conditions

Tags: mysql

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)          
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
WHERE (FieldName = 'Resa Agapes' AND FieldValue = 'OUI')
AND (FieldName = 'Validation Paiement Agapes' AND FieldValue = 'NON')
```

But it's not working well.

In fact, I need to count how many line I have where `Resa Agapes = OUI + Validation Paiement Agapes=NON`

Sreenshot to my table:
[image]

Comment: Give description of `jos_rsform_submission_values`. There are must be field what will be using for aggregation of fileds in frame of one submission

Comment: @mnv thanks ty try to help me. sorry but i not sure to understand your question 'jos_rsform_submission_values' contain submitionId to link FieldName and FieldValue

Comment: mnv is asking you to show the table structure. Run DESCRIBE jos_rsform_submission_values; and add the output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you get on the right track. It assumes you have an id column of some name or other. If you provide a bit more info I'll try to help polish this up.

```
SELECT COUNT(id), FieldName, FieldValue
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values  
GROUP BY  FieldName
```

Answer (score 0):

If submission id contains in field `sumbissionId`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cnt = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM (
    SELECT sumbissionId, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
    WHERE ((FieldName = 'Resa Agapes' AND FieldValue = 'OUI')
        OR (FieldName = 'Validation Paiement Agapes' AND FieldValue = 'NON'))
    AND FormId = 1
    GROUP BY sumbissionId
) t
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite right - it's hard to say without a table structure, but grouping by a primary key will only give counts of 1.

Comment: ...but it's possible that I just don't understand the question

Comment: I assume what `jos_rsform_submission_values` contains form values. So every post must have some identifier, `sumbission_id` is not primary key. It play role of that identifier.

Comment: Ahhh. Fair enough.I suppose we're both guessing a bit :)

Comment: is it possible to link a screenshot here?

Comment: Yes, ok, we just need more info

Comment: Try this query, it calculating how many submissions with needed values of two fields.

Comment: It is just alias for result of subquery - it may be any name, `my_subquery_table`, for example

Answer (score 0):

```
FieldName = 'Resa Agapes' AND FieldName = 'Validation Paiement Agapes'
```

...from one table always give NULLLLLL....

View of table structure could help in making query :)

greets
niktom

Answer (score 0):

It's solved thanks to mnv to resolv my query:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN cnt = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM (
SELECT submissionId, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM jos_rsform_submission_values
WHERE ((FieldName = 'Resa Agapes' AND FieldValue = 'OUI')
    OR (FieldName = 'Validation Paiement Agapes' AND FieldValue = 'NON'))
AND FormId = 1
GROUP BY submissionId ) t
```